# Asp .net c#:Why does Html Table not show in Outlook mail

Tags: c#, html, datatable, outlook, smtp

I am building a web application using asp.net mvc and in my controller I have a method to send  a table from a Sql Server database in the body of an email to a user that would be entered in the textbox field of the view. The email is working however when I try sending to an outlook account the html attributes seem to be removed leaving just the raw data. I find it strange because it works on gmail and yahoo but not with Microsoft accounts.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SendMail(ResultsArchive res)
        {
            DataTable table;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string queryArchive = "Select [ID],[ProfileDate],[GroupSubsidiary],[FunctionName],[CheckPeriod],[AlertStatus],[Comment], [Instance] FROM [datamart2].[dbo].[AS2_AlertsResultsArchive] Where convert(varchar, ProfileDate, 101) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)  ";
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            sqlcon.Open();
          
                
            SqlCommand Archsqlcmd = new SqlCommand(queryArchive, sqlcon);                
                
            dt.Load(Archsqlcmd.ExecuteReader());
            sqlcon.Close();
            table = dt;
            
            string messageBody = " See Records";
            
            string htmlTableStart = "<table1 style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align: center;\" >";
            string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
            string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style=\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
            string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
            string htmlTrStart = "<tr style=\"color:#555555 \">";
            string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
            string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\"border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
            string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";
            messageBody += htmlTableStart;
            messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "ID" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "ProfileDate" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "GroupSubsidiary" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "FunctionName" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "CheckPeriod" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "AlertStatus" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "Comment" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "Instance" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;
            for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrStart;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][0] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][1] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][2] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][3] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][4] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][5] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][6] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][7] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrEnd;
            }
            messageBody = messageBody + htmlTableEnd;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(res.To);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("blahblah@outlook.com");                
                mail.Subject = "JMMB Daily Alerts checks for '"+DateTime.Now+"'";
                var Message = "Good Day," + "\r\n " + "\r\n"  ;
                Message += "See the daily alert checks below" + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
                //Message += "<table><thead><tr>";
                Message += messageBody;
                //Message += "</tr></thead>";
                //Message += dt;
                mail.Body = Message;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blahblah@outlook", "fakepass");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Timeout = 200000;
                smtp.Send(mail);
               
                return new EmptyResult();
            }
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

In gmail it comes out perfectly:

[image]

But in Outlook it comes with the table format

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is causing the discrepancies in the emails?

Thank You.

Comment: Is your email set to TEXT or HTML.  Table will be remove if you are set to receive only TEXT email messages (not html nor RTF{rich text]).

Comment: Your opening `table` tag looks incorrect, you have `"<table1 style=...`

Comment: @stuartd It works. That small issue was the problem, thank you noticing the detail, but why did it still work with the other mail services like gmail?

Comment: They're probably more forgiving of malformed markup